# Fastest way to find exact match of long text string in large SQL db

Tags: sql, performance

My db table will have a col "a" TEXT with long strings, like multiple paragraphs. Given an input string, I want to find the one matching record. If the table has millions of rows, what would be faster? A simple

```
WHERE a = ?
```

Or should I calc and store a md5 hash of each row and then match that? Suggestions welcome.

Comment: Will the input string be an exact match, or a "contains" relationship?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an exact match, it will be much quicker to store the hash and compare to that.  It will preclude substring searches, but it's much quicker to compare say 4 characters than to check thousands.

There will be some overhead to calculate the hash on your search parameter, but it's nothing compared to a string comparison against that much data.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that. I haven't tested yet, but that is my assumption as well. And, yes, the matches have to be complete and exact, spaces and all.

Comment: I agree with that, especially when matching will be done far often then inserting.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using SQL Server you could for the Full-Text-Search feature

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx

Comment: Probably overkill for this use case, but still good to know about.